# Запись звука из flash на сервер

Tags: flash

Требуется организовать запись звука с флешки запущенной в браузере пользователя на сервер.

Можно ли как нибудь это сделать без использования rtmp сервера?
Например, передачей потока POST запросом(пусть даже в виде 30-ти секундных отрезков) PHP скрипту.
При этом, передача нужна постоянной, чтобы при выключении флешки, все что успел сказать пользователь в микрофон, было на сервере.

Может быть существует еще какие то способы?

Буду очень признателен за ссылки или подсказки технологий.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запись/Воспроизведение звука в ByteArray - http://forums.adobe.com/thread/596429

Дальше отправляем строку POST запросом. Строку строим из первичного ByteArray - http://as3coder.blogspot.com/2010/02/bytearray-xml.html

При постоянной записи 30 секунд слишком много, надо будет чаще скидывать буфер на сервер.

Вот есть библиотека для записи с сжатием - http://code.google.com/p/micrecorder/downloads/detail?name=MicRecorder%201.2.zip&can=2&q=